# Can this jQuery/Javascript functionality be replicated with PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

This is the code to grab tweets, but i need this in PHP, can anybody offer any insight?

```
$(document).ready( function() {

            var url = "http://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/joebloggs.json?count=1&callback=?";
            $.getJSON(url,
            function(data){
                $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                    $("#twitter-posts").append("<p>" + item.text.linkify() + " <span class='created_at'>" + relative_time(item.created_at) + " via " + item.source + "</span></p>");
                });
            });
        });

        String.prototype.linkify = function() {
            return this.replace(/[A-Za-z]+:\/\/[A-Za-z0-9-_]+\.[A-Za-z0-9-_:%&\?\/.=]+/, function(m) {
        return m.link(m);
      });
     }; 
      function relative_time(time_value) {
          var values = time_value.split(" ");
          time_value = values[1] + " " + values[2] + ", " + values[5] + " " + values[3];
          var parsed_date = Date.parse(time_value);
          var relative_to = (arguments.length > 1) ? arguments[1] : new Date();
          var delta = parseInt((relative_to.getTime() - parsed_date) / 1000);
          delta = delta + (relative_to.getTimezoneOffset() * 60);

          var r = '';
          if (delta < 60) {
            r = 'a minute ago';
          } else if(delta < 120) {
            r = 'couple of minutes ago';
          } else if(delta < (45*60)) {
            r = (parseInt(delta / 60)).toString() + ' minutes ago';
          } else if(delta < (90*60)) {
            r = 'an hour ago';
          } else if(delta < (24*60*60)) {
            r = '' + (parseInt(delta / 3600)).toString() + ' hours ago';
          } else if(delta < (48*60*60)) {
            r = '1 day ago';
          } else {
            r = (parseInt(delta / 86400)).toString() + ' days ago';
          }

          return r;
    }
    function twitter_callback ()
    {
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: **Yes, it can be replicated in PHP.** What have you tried? Just do what it does. The only "issue" may be if the sites require cookies -- set in a web-browser client, but perhaps not by the PHP code -- to serve up the content.

Comment: with? any specific functions you could point me to

Comment: @benhowdle89 Exactly which part is "giving problems"? Numerous functions and operators will ultimately be used, just as they are in JS. Are you asking "how can I download a web resource" in PHP? Or is there something else?

Comment: The fact that this code preserves twitter hashtags, hyperlinks, i thought the PHP would just bring back dumb text

Comment: @benhowdle89 JSON is "dumb text" :-) That is why you use a JSON-library/function to turn it into a structure to manipulate. jQuery does this automatically: "dumb text" -> JavaScript object(s). In PHP it'd just be "dumb text" -> some PHP object.

Comment: thanks pst, i'm attempting to run some PHP code on a cron job, grab a users latest tweets, store them in a database but preserving links and hashtags in the tweets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most complicated part is the request to twitter, you can do something like that:

```
$content = file_get_contents("http://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/joebloggs.json?count=1&callback=?");

$twitter_response = json_decode($content);

foreach($twitter_response as $item){
      //format someway
      $item->text; #get the text of each tweet

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use cURL to access the file. Then use the PHP function `json_decode` to work with the data.

[PHP: cURL](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)
[PHP: json_decode](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/joebloggs.json?count=1&callback=?");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$json = json_decode($result);
var_dump($json);
```

Comment: thanks Michael, would this preserve Twitter hashtags or hyperlinks?

Comment: No idea, to be completely honest. That code is theoretical; I have not tested it. But, I've done similar requests in the past from other sites.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it. For the major parts you can use cURL or file_get_contents to fetch the data, json_decode to parse it.